# En código Javascript siempre se elimina la clase con display: none del último objeto del array y no sé cómo hacer para que esto no suceda

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, javascript-objeto

En este código la idea es que para cada película del array haya un botón que, al clickearlo, muestre el trailer respectivo en un modal, eliminando la clase que tiene con display:none.

Esto funciona cuando es una sola película ya que puedo seleccionar ese botón específico a partir de un ID o una clase, pero cuando son varias las películas, al clickear el botón de Ver trailer, siempre me muestra el modal de la última película, ya que siempre se va a eliminar la clase con display:none del último objeto del array.

¿Cómo hacer para que esto no suceda?

```
// VARIANTE CON UNA SOLA PELÍCULA Y EJEMPLO DE FUNCIONAMIENTO

const showTrailer = document.querySelector('#show-trailer');
const closeTrailer = document.querySelector('#close-trailer');
const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-container');

showTrailer.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.classList.add('visible')
})

closeTrailer.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.classList.remove('visible')

    // detiene el video cuando se pulsa cerrar, de lo contrario el sonido sigue en el background
    let iframes = modal.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    if (iframes != null) {
        for (let i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
            const iframe = iframes[i];
            iframe.src = iframe.src;
        }
    }
})

// VARIANTE CON EL ARRAY DE PELÍCULAS

class Pelicula {

    constructor(name, year, director, genre, language, image, imdb, rate, trailer) {
        this.name = name,
        this.year = year,
        this.director = director,
        this.genre = genre,
        this.language = language,

        this.image = image,
        this.imdb = imdb

        this.rate = rate
        this.trailer = trailer
    }
}

let bastardosSinGloria = new Pelicula('Inglourious Basterds', 2009, 'Quentin Tarantino', ['accion'], 'inglés', 'assets/img/inglourious-basterds.jpg', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0361748/', 8.3, 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/aoCUJrmskas');
let threeBillboards = new Pelicula('Three Billboards Outside Ebbing, Missouri', 2017, 'Martin McDonagh', ['drama'], 'inglés', 'assets/img/three-billboards.jpg', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5027774/', 8.1, 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jit3YhGx5pU')
let exorcismEmily = new Pelicula('The Exorcism of Emily Rose', 2005, 'Scott Derrickson', ['terror'], 'inglés', 'assets/img/emily-rose.jpg', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0404032/', 6.7, 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bi-PLwxwvy8');

let arrayPeliculas = [bastardosSinGloria, threeBillboards, exorcismEmily]


//----------------


let template = document.querySelector('.template-trailer').content
let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
let divContainer = document.querySelector('#div_container')

arrayPeliculas.forEach(el => {

    template.querySelector('button').classList.add((el.name).join)

    template.querySelector('h3').textContent = el.name
    template.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute('src', el.trailer)

    let clone = document.importNode(template, true)
    fragment.appendChild(clone)

})

divContainer.appendChild(fragment)



$('.show-trailer').on('click', () => {
    $('.modal-container').addClass('visible')
})

$('.close-trailer').on('click', () => {
    $('.modal-container').removeClass('visible')
})




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- TÍTULO -->
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- ESTILOS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
    <!-- Script -->
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- EJEMPLO PARA UNA SOLA PELÍCULA -->

    <div class="trailer-container" style="margin-bottom: 8rem">

        <div><img style="width: 10rem" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71gjqgxSWsL._AC_SL1000_.jpg" alt=""></div>

        <button id="show-trailer" type="button"><i class="bi bi-film"></i> Ver trailer</button>

        <div id="modal-container">

            <div class="modal">
    
                <button id="close-trailer" type="button"><i class="bi bi-x-lg"></i></button>
    
                <div class="iframe-container">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-UaGUdNJdRQ" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
        </div>

    </div>


    
    <!-- EJEMPLO PARA EL ARRAY -->

    <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 3rem; color: blue">Variante con el array de Películas</h2>
    
    <template class="template-trailer">

        <h3></h3>

        <div class="trailer-container">

            <button class="show-trailer" type="button"><i class="bi bi-film"></i> Ver trailer</button>
    
            <div id="modal_container" class="modal-container">
                <div class="modal">
                    <button class="close-trailer" type="button"><i class="bi bi-x-lg"></i></button>
                    <div class="iframe-container">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
        
    </template>

    <!-- CONTAINER -->

    <div id="div_container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para facilitar las cosas, es mejor trabajar con una sola ventana modal, reduces código y evitas tener que detectar cuál es la que se está mostrando. En su lugar, usa [atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) para guardar en el botón la URL del video.

Cuando se haga clic en un botón, con [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) identificas en cuál botón se hizo clic, desde ahí obtienes la URL del video y la asignas al `iframe`.

Otro cambio importante es evitar modificar la plantilla (`template`), el primer paso es clonarla y ya puedes aplicar los cambios necesarios sobre el nuevo elemento.

En la misma plantilla se agrega un contenedor para agrupar los datos de cada película; esto te va a permitir mayor flexibilidad al dar formato y seleccionar elementos internos.

```js
class Pelicula {
    constructor(name, year, director, genre, language, image, imdb, rate, trailer) {
        this.name = name,
        this.year = year,
        this.director = director,
        this.genre = genre,
        this.language = language,

        this.image = image,
        this.imdb = imdb

        this.rate = rate
        this.trailer = trailer
    }
};

let bastardosSinGloria = new Pelicula('Inglourious Basterds', 2009, 'Quentin Tarantino', ['accion'], 'inglés', 'assets/img/inglourious-basterds.jpg', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0361748/', 8.3, 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/aoCUJrmskas');
let threeBillboards = new Pelicula('Three Billboards Outside Ebbing, Missouri', 2017, 'Martin McDonagh', ['drama'], 'inglés', 'assets/img/three-billboards.jpg', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5027774/', 8.1, 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jit3YhGx5pU')
let exorcismEmily = new Pelicula('The Exorcism of Emily Rose', 2005, 'Scott Derrickson', ['terror'], 'inglés', 'assets/img/emily-rose.jpg', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0404032/', 6.7, 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bi-PLwxwvy8');

let arrayPeliculas = [bastardosSinGloria, threeBillboards, exorcismEmily]


//----------------


let template = document.querySelector('.template-trailer').content
let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
let divContainer = document.querySelector('#div_container')

arrayPeliculas.forEach(el => {
    // Primero clona la plantilla
    let clone = document.importNode(template, true);
    // Trabaja sobre el clon
    clone.querySelector('h3').textContent = el.name;
    // Coloca el video en atributo de datos del botón
    clone.querySelector('button').dataset.src = el.trailer;
    // Esta línea devuelve undefined, el.name es una cadena
    // clone.querySelector('button').classList.add((el.name).join);
    fragment.appendChild(clone);
});

divContainer.appendChild(fragment);


// Recibir evento en la función, variable "e"
$('.show-trailer').on('click', (e) => {
    // Abrir modal
    $('.modal-container').addClass('visible');
    // Obtener iframe y asignar URL guardada en el botón
    $('.modal-container').find('iframe').attr('src', $(e.currentTarget).data('src'));
});

$('.close-trailer').on('click', () => {
    // Ocultar modal
    $('.modal-container').removeClass('visible');
    // Parar video, poniendo la URL en blanco
    $('.modal-container').find('iframe').attr('src', '');
});
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- EJEMPLO PARA EL ARRAY -->

    <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 3rem; color: blue">Variante con el array de Películas</h2>

    <!-- Se agrega div con clase film-container para agrupar datos de cada película -->
    <template class="template-trailer">
        <div class="film-container">
            <h3></h3>
            <div class="trailer-container">
                <button class="show-trailer" data-src="" type="button"><i class="bi bi-film"></i> Ver trailer</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <!-- CONTAINER -->

    <div id="div_container"></div>

    <!-- Una sola modal para todas las películas -->
    <div id="modal_container" class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal">
            <button class="close-trailer" type="button"><i class="bi bi-x-lg"></i></button>
            <div class="iframe-container">
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

En caso de que no te guste esta propuesta y quieras continuar con lo que ya tienes, solo necesitas recibir el evento en ambas funciones y detectar cuál modal es la que se va a abrir o cerrar.

**Importante:** Funciona solo si creas el contenedor para cada película, en este ejemplo, con clase `film-container`.

```
$('.show-trailer').on('click', (e) => {
    // e.currentTarget es el botón en que se hizo clic
    // .closest() sirve para seleccionar el contenedor de la película
    // .find() selecciona la modal correspondiente a esa película
    $(e.currentTarget).closest('.film-container').find('.modal-container').addClass('visible');
});

$('.close-trailer').on('click', (e) => {
    // e.currentTarget es el botón de cerrar modal
    // .closest() selecciona la modal a la que pertenece el botón
    $(e.currentTarget).closest('.modal-container').removeClass('visible');
    // Solo falta detener el video
});
```